# cffunction: second argument based on first argument

Tags: function, coldfusion, arguments

I have following code that first creates an object and afterwards it calls a function called init.

```
<cfset SESSION.objWatchlist = createObject("component", "path") />
<cfset SESSION.objWatchlist.init(session.addressid) />
```

So far so good. The init function looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="init" access="remote" output="false">
  <cfargument name="addressID" type="numeric" required="true" />
  <cfset THIS.ADDRESSID = arguments.addressID />
  <cfset THIS.WATCHLIST = arrayNew(1) />
  <cfset initWatchlistArray() />
  <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>
```

Now I want to add another argument to the cffunction. I will call it like this:

```
<cfset SESSION.objWatchlist.init("addressid", session.addressid) />
```

and

```
<cfset SESSION.objWatchlist.init("sessionid", session.sessionid) />
```

I add some new lines in the cffunction:

```
<cffunction name="init" access="remote" output="false">
  <cfargument name="typeOfID" type="string" required="true" />
  <cfif arguments.typeOfID eq "addressid">
     <cfargument name="addressID" type="numeric" required="true" />
     <cfset THIS.ADDRESSID = arguments.addressID />
  <cfelseif arguments.typeOfID eq "sessionid">
     <cfargument name="sessionID" type="string" required="true" />
     <cfset THIS.SESSIONID = arguments.sessionID />
  </cfif>
  <cfset THIS.WATCHLIST = arrayNew(1) />
  <cfset initWatchlistArray() />
  <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>
```

But everytime I get the error "The tag must be nested inside a CFFUNCTION tag".

Now my question is how can I write a function in which the second argument is based on the first one?

Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to have variables in the `this` scope, declare them outside a function.  You can give them values inside a function.  Regarding the actual question, declare all the arguments and transfer any logic to later on in the function.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an example for that?

Comment: At bit a off topic. This type of code should be in `<cfscript>`. It will be much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I have found a solution that looks like that:

First I call the function:

```
<cfset SESSION.objWatchlist.init(addressID=session.addressid) />
<cfset SESSION.objWatchlist.init(sessionID=session.sessionid) />
```

I changed the function to following:

```
<cffunction name="init" access="remote" output="false">
  <cfargument name="addressID" type="numeric" required="false" />    
  <cfargument name="sessionID" type="string" required="false" />
  <cfif isDefined("arguments.addressid")>
    <cfset THIS.ADDRESSID = arguments.addressID />
  <cfelseif isDefined("arguments.sessionid")>
    <cfset THIS.SESSIONID = arguments.sessionid />
  </cfif>  
  <cfset THIS.WATCHLIST = arrayNew(1) />
  <cfset initWatchlistArray() />
  <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>
```

When calling the function I can call them with the name of the argument in the cffunction.
Afterwards I can check which one is defined.

Comment: Just to add a clarity (I hope) to your changes. Your original problem was that cfarguments can only be declared at the top of a function. They cannot be nested inside a conditional. From Adobe docs on cfargument: "This tag must be in a cffunction tag, before any other tags in the cffunction tag body." That was why you received the error you did.

I would point out that this new code could accept both an addressID and a sessionID parameter and if that happens the sessionID is not going to be set because it is only set if arguments.addressID is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but I have a little cleanup on this

```
SESSION.objWatchlist.init(addressID=session.addressid);
SESSION.objWatchlist.init(sessionID=session.sessionid);


any function init(numeric addressID, string sessionid) access="remote" output="false" {

   if (arguments.keyexists(("addressid"))    { THIS.ADDRESSID = arguments.addressID; }
   else if (arguments.keyexists("sessionid") { THIS.SESSIONID = arguments.sessionid; }

   THIS.WATCHLIST = [];
   initWatchlistArray();
   return this;
 }
```

Note: the use of `.keyexists()`. This is a faster check because it does not have to look through every scope that could have something that matches.

Also note it is easier to blank out an array.